# If I use Invoke-Command succesfully, does that mean that I have RDP access aswell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, remote-desktop

I am using the Invoke-Command like this:

```
Invoke-Command @parameters
```

Credentials like this:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
```

And parameters like this:

```
$parameters = @{
  ComputerName      = "myHost"
  Credential        = $credentials
  ScriptBlock       = { some code here }
}
```

If I can succesfully execute code on **myHost** using the credentials that I provide, does this also mean that I can 100% guarantee that I could login using RDP (mstsc.exe) with the same credentials? Eventually, I want to check if I can login using RDP on myHost using Powershell.

Comment: No, `Invoke-Command` uses the WinRM (Microsofts Implementation of the WS-Management Protocol) to connect to a remote machine via Port 5985 or 5986. RDP uses Port 3389 and the RDP Protocol. You need to manually allow RDP connections to the computer and even allow certain users to connect to RDP (do this via GPO)

Comment: RDP is a different service that needs to be running: `TermService`. It listens on a different port: 3389 (so check firewall). And it technically requires a different set of privileges. By default, powershell allows `Remote Management Users` to connect, and RDP allows `Remote Desktop Users` (both allow Administrators)

Comment: Is it possible to user $credentials just to check if the user still has access to myHost, without actually open the remote desktop interface? I would prefer a simple message in the console saying "user has access to myHost".

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Command` requires `PSRemoting` to be enabled on the remote machine. By Default, the domain admin and local admin groups are able to run remote commands. Other users/service accounts can be added individually that are not a part of these groups. Users can be added to run remote commands by opening a Windows Powershell session as Administrator and entering `Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -Force`  and adding their account.

`Remote Desktop` requires users to be added to the `Remote Desktop Users` group or be in the `Local/Domain Administrators` group.

To answer you specific question, usually, if you can successfully run `Invoke-Command` , you will also be able to remote desktop, but not always.

You can check the `Administrators` group and the `Remote Desktop Users` group using `Invoke-Command` to see if the account you are using is listed there. This will iterate and list the groups and members of these groups on the local machine.

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -Computer "MyRemotePCName" -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock { Get-LocalGroupMember -group "Administrators"; Get-LocalGroupMember -group "Remote Desktop Users" }
```

Comment: Is it possible to user $credentials just to check if the user still has access to myHost, without actually open the remote desktop interface? I would prefer a simple message in the console saying "user has access to myHost".

Comment: Yes, you can check the `Administrators` group and the `Remote Desktop Users` group using `Invoke-Command` to see if the account you are using is listed there. `Invoke-Command -Computer "MyRemotePCName" -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock { Get-LocalGroupMember -group "Administrators"; Get-LocalGroupMember -group "Remote Desktop Users" }`